# How get NA for values which are not found in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a vector of values and a dataframe which I can find each item of a vector in a specific column of dataframe with the following command:

```
lapply(l, function(x) df[which(df$col1==x),col2])
```

How can I get NA for values which are not available in my dataframe?

For example:

```
df:   col1  col2
      1     a
      1     b
      2     c

l=c(1,3)

output:  col1   col2
         1      a,b
         3      NA
```

Comment: Not much clear to me. Post some inputs and the desired output.

Comment: Please provide example data for your `l` and `df` objects as well as the expected output.

Comment: when I use unlist to get the output of this function, all charater(0) values are removed. I want to get NA after using unlist for these values.

Comment: Please provide [reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: example is provided

Comment: You are probably coming from Python. a `list` in Python and in R are different things. In your case you have a numeric vector. Also, `list` is a bad way to call it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function which gives TRUE if sth is NOT integer(0), character(0), etc.
(they have in common that their length is zero):

```
non.zero.vec <- function(x) length(x) > 0
```

Any vector with such zero-length-value elements can be converted to NA using

```
zero2na <- function(vec) sapply(vec, function(x) ifelse(non.zero.vec(x), x, NA))

## e.g.
zero2na(c(1, 2, integer(0)) ## [1] 1 2 NA
```

Finally, this function does exactly what you want:

```
lookup <- function(df, key.col, val.col, keys) {
  idxs <- lapply(keys, function(x) which(df[, key.col] == x))
  lookups <- lapply(idxs, function(vec) if(length(vec) > 0) {df[vec , val.col]} else {NA})
  lookupstrings <- unlist(lapply(lookups, 
    function(v) suppressWarnings(if(is.na(v)) {"NA"} else {paste(v, collapse = ", ")})))
  res.df <- data.frame(unlist(keys), lookupstrings)
  colnames(res.df) <- c(key.col, val.col)
  res.df
}

df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1,1,2), col2 = c("a", "b", "c"))
lookup(df, "col1", "col2", c(1, 2, 3))

## output:

  col1 col2
1    1 a, b
2    2    c
3    3   NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Using data.table you could achieve this efficiently by running a binary join to `l` (your vector)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[.(l), # join between `df` & `l`
          on = .(col1), # using `col1`
          .(col2 = toString(col2)), # paste the values in `col2` (you can add `unique`)
          by = .EACHI] # do this per each value in `l`
#    col1 col2
# 1:    1 a, b
# 2:    3   NA
```

Comment: It's really short and simple (+1)!

Answer (score 1):

**DATA:**

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c(1L, 1L, 2L), col2 = c("a", "b", "c")), .Names = c("col1","col2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
l <- c(1, 3)
```

**CODE:**

```
library(magrittr)
lapply(l, function(x){
    res<-df[[2]][df[[1]]==x] %>% paste(collapse=",")
    if(res=="") res = NA
    return(cbind(x,res))
    }) %>% do.call(rbind,.)
```

**Result:**

```
     x   res  
[1,] "1" "a,b"
[2,] "3" NA
```